# Laptop that does not hibernate on idle automatically. Why?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

I have a Dell Inspirion 15 running Windows 8 which is set to hibernate automatically after 20 mins as far as I can tell from the Power Profile (see screenshot below). But somehow it never hibernates automatically when connected to the charger. No matter how long its idling.

[image]

I can get it to hibernate manually, no trouble.

Any ideas what setting I'm getting wrong? How can I debug this?

I think I'm using the "Balanced" Power Profile. [image]

Edit: As far as I can tell both wake timers are already disabled. [image]

Also, here's a list of Scheduled tasks if anyone can identify an obvious culprit.[image]

Comment: what state and profile are you currently using in each of these screenshots. i.e. plugged in? not? which power profile is active? I see balance is active in one? is it for the other?

Comment: It is possible for a Scheduled Task to keep a pc from entering hibernation/sleep. In order to determine this, I would first rule out if its something currently active that prevents sleep by setting the timer very shortly, like a minute or so. If that does work, increase the timer until it doesn't work at all. Then look at the frequency and detemine if there's a scheduled task that runs about the same amount of times a day.

Comment: @Nalaurien Thanks! How can I find out? I've posed another screenshot in my Question. I think I'm using "Balanced". Or did I not understand your question correctly?

Comment: ok so go back to power options, and under your current plan settings click advanced power settings. then find **sleep** and expand that catagory. We are looking for something called "Allow wake timers". If that is enabled, disable it.

Comment: @Nalaurien Thanks. I posted a new screenshot. Both Wake timers seem disabled.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks. I've edited my question and posted a list of scheduled tasks. Can you see any obvious conflicts?

Comment: im gonna do some tests, ill get back to you on this.

Comment: Have you tested if the system goes into hibernation when you set the timer to 1 minute? if it doesn't work then either, then you can rule out a scheduled task, unless its the synaptic touchpad one, given that its currently running.

Comment: @LPChip Tried the 1 min hibernate setting. Still does not hibernate. Thoughts?

Comment: So that means there currently is an application active that prevents the laptop from going to sleep. You could close all programs using task manager so only the bare basic remains and see if the 1 min hibernation works again. If so, start programs until it stops working. Also stop that task that is running. It may be the problem.